# Can not read from opened file

Tags: c, linux, file, io, posix

The file exists and I have just read from it in another function. The other function closes the file. Now, my `workwith()` tries to open it and read from it.

My code:

```
if (access(path_file, F_OK) != -1) {
  // file exists
  *mfs_desc = open(path_file, O_WRONLY | O_RDONLY, 0600);
  if (*mfs_desc == -1) {
    perror("opening file");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("file_descriptor = %d, filename = |%s|\n", *mfs_desc,
         path_file);
  if ((read(*mfs_desc, superblock, sizeof(Superblock))) == - 1) {
    perror("read superblock");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

However, I am getting this output:

```
file_descriptor = 3, filename = |t.mfs|
read superblock: Bad file descriptor
```

I suspect that the way I am opening the file is not correct. I want to open the file for writing and reading purposes. The file already exists. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this flags

```
O_WRONLY | O_RDONLY
```

to

```
O_RDWR
```

check [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), it says that the flags must include **one** of the access modes.

Moreover, the ref mentions:

> The argument flags must include one of the following access modes:
>          O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.  These request opening the file read-
>          only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.

Comment: They don't `|` together nicely because originally the "mode" was just a boolean indicating whether you wanted write access or not. Read-write mode didn't exist. When it was added, the numeric value of readonly was kept at 0 for compatibility. [V3 man page](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man2/open.2) [V4 man page](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V4/man/man2/open.2) ... I think Ken and Dennis were smart enough to know that `O_RDWR != O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY` was silly and would have fixed it if they could.